# CupertinoThemeData doesn't use specified primary color?

Tags: flutter

I have a class where I specify `ThemeData` for my app.
I use this class to set the appropriate theme in either the `MaterialApp` or `CupertinoApp`.

```
return CupertinoApp(
//...
theme: AppicationTheme.iosTheme()
//...
);
```

My IOS theme is provided as follows

```
static CupertinoThemeData iosTheme(){
 return CupertinoThemeData(primaryColor: myPrimaryColor);
}
```

However when trying to set the color on an `Icon`, the primary color is still default blue as if never set to my color.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using `Theme.of(context).primaryColor`,
switch `Theme` to `CupertinoTheme`.

example:

```
Icon(Icons.access_alarm,<br>
     color: CupertinoTheme.of(context).primaryColor,
),
```